# Htaccess Querystring Key Rewrite without change path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, key, query-string

I have a URL like this:

`example.com/this/that.html?zona=my-zona`

and I need to rewrite and do a 301 to:

`example.com/this/that.html?loc=my-zona`

I need to keep the path and the querystring value for the key 'zona' the same but I need to rewrite 'zona' key to 'loc'

Answer (score 0):

You can change this rule at top of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^zona=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^this/that\.html$ %{REQUEST_URI}?loc=%1 [L,NC,R=301]
```